# Form Validation error while using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, sharepoint

I'm trying to add a simple validation for my input text box using angularjs and trying to show an inline error message. I have tried a lot, but still I'm not able to get the `$valid`, `$ error`, `$invalid` etc. These attributes are getting as undefined. I have given the reference to angularjs.js file. All other functionalities are working, but don't know what's happening. I'm new to angularjs, hope someone will help me in this regard. My code snippet is given below.

```
<sp-modal-dialog show='modalShown'>
    <label for="title">Title <span>*</span></label>
    <input type="text" name="txtTitle" ng-model="Model.Title" ng-maxlength="20" required>
    <div ng-show="popupForm.txtTitle.$invalid">Invalid:
    <span ng-show="popupForm.txtTitle.$error.required">Title is mandatory.</span>
    <span ng-show="popupForm.txtTitle.$error.maxlength">Title should contain atleast 20 characters.</span>
    </div>
```

EDIT:
I'm using a directive to show the popup form. Please see the code below.

```
//Directive to link the modalDialog as Element
contextualHelpModule.directive('spModalDialog', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            show: '='
        },
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.hideModal = function () {
                scope.show = false;
            };
        },
        template: '<form id="popupForm" name="popupForm"  novalidate><div ng-show="show"><div class="popup-main" ng-show="show"><div class="popup-container"><div class="popup-content" ng-transclude><div ng-click="hideModal()" class="popup-close">X</div></div></div></div><div class="popup-overlay"></div></div></form>'
    };
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to wrap that into a form:

```
<form name="popupForm">
 <label for="title">Title <span>*</span></label>
 <input type="text" name="txtTitle" ng-model="Model.Title" ng-maxlength="20" required>
 <div ng-show="popupForm.txtTitle.$invalid">Invalid:
  <span ng-show="popupForm.txtTitle.$error.required">Title is mandatory.</span>
  <span ng-show="popupForm.txtTitle.$error.maxlength">Title should contain atleast 20 characters.</span>
 </div>
</form>
```

I hope that it helps.

Comment: I have already wrapped it with the form tag. Sorry to miss that out in the given code.

Comment: I cannot see what it is not working. Can you show your controller?

Comment: I'm using a directive to show the popup form. I have updated the question with that.

Comment: Your form doesn't have the name="popupForm". Here-> template: '<form id="popupForm"  novalidate>

Comment: I have changed it. See the updated code. Still the same result. It seems the class is updating correctly as ng-valid, ng-invalid etc in the background. But, popupForm.txtTitle.$invalid is undefined!

Comment: I canot see the problem, if you make a fiddle with your code, I would be able to give you more information.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as jvrdelafuente explains, you will need to wrap it in a

```
<form name="popupForm">
```

tag.  Once you do that, then you will have access to the properties via popupForm.txtTitle.$error.required, etc.  Otherwise, they are not defined as you have observed.  Unfortunately, I have recently learned that if you are placing your form tag in an aspx page using a SharePoint master page, the master page places its own form tag without a name attribute.  ASP.NET will then strip your form out because it does not allow a form within a form.  I am still searching for the rest of the story.

Update....

To be able to get past the issue with ASP.NET stripping out the AngularJS form tag, use an ng-form tag instead:

```
<ng-form name="popupForm">
  <label for="title">Title <span>*</span></label>
  <input type="text" name="txtTitle" ng-model="Model.Title" ng-maxlength="20" required>
  <div ng-show="popupForm.txtTitle.$invalid">Invalid:
    <span ng-show="popupForm.txtTitle.$error.required">Title is mandatory.</span>
    <span ng-show="popupForm.txtTitle.$error.maxlength">Title should contain atleast 20 characters.</span>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **ng-form** at place of **form**, it will work fine, as see code in below

```
<ng-form name="popupForm">
   <label for="title">Title <span>*</span></label>
   <input type="text" name="txtTitle" ng-model="Model.Title" ng-maxlength="20" required>
   <div ng-show="popupForm.txtTitle.$invalid">Invalid:
   <span ng-show="popupForm.txtTitle.$error.required">Title is mandatory.</span>
   <span ng-show="popupForm.txtTitle.$error.maxlength">Title should contain  atleast 20 characters.</span>
   </div>
</ng-form>
```